# Simple JSF layoutunit

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am new to JSF i am using primefaces,

I have to layoutunits center and north, in the north layout I have inputtext and commandbutton, I just simply want to enter a url in inputbox and when I click on the commandbutton the url is displayed in the center layoutunit.

the code is given below

```
<h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">

        <p:layoutUnit position="north">
            <p:inputText id="inputUrl" />
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" />
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerLayout">
        </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Why exactly is this question tagged `[jsf-1.2]`? I see only JSF 2.x compatible PrimeFaces code, not JSF 1.2 code. Why exactly is this question tagged `[ajax4jsf]`? I see only PrimeFaces code, not Ajax4jsf code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set value for commandlink and update it as shown below.

It works.

```
<h:form id="form">

<p:layout fullPage="true" id="main">


<p:layoutUnit position="north">
    <p:inputText id="inputUrl" value="#{formBeanBB.url}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Submit"  actionListener="#{formBeanBB.displayLink}" update="links,inputUrl"/>
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerLayout">
<h:panelGrid id="links">

<p:commandLink value="#{formBeanBB.link}" />
</h:panelGrid>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

```
BackingBean

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FormBeanBB implements Serializable{

private String url;
private String link;


 public void displayLink(){


          setLink(url);

          setUrl("");
      }

    public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getLink() {
            return link;
        }

        public void setLink(String link) {
            this.link = link;
        }  


}
```

Comment: is this possible through ajax

Comment: yes why not? You can simply apply `ajax` call to inputtext, but this doesn't make any sense as whenever you will try to type anything into inputtext it will ajax method, and then for all ajax you will update this commandlink. This is not good way...